# getCurrentItem give me true value but metot return 0

Tags: java, android, return, return-value

`getCurrentItem` value is 14 but returns 0. Why return 0? I don't understand.

And how to send data between 2 classes?

MainActivity.java

```
//this code return 0 but I get log retrun not 0

public int normal() {
 Log.i("deneme",mFlippableStack.getCurrentItem()+ "");
  //I/deneme: 14

    return mFlippableStack.getCurrentItem();


    }
```

ColorFragment.java

```
MainActivity abc = new MainActivity();

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+abc.normal(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Toast message give me 0

Comment: does `getCurrentItem()` by any chance `pop()` the value from the stack? In this case, it would not be surprising that two consecutive calls to `getCurrentItem()` return different values.

Comment: you are creating a instance of MainActivity in ColorFragment and expecting it to give you the result of previous instance ? how could it possible. use any callback and pass it to colorfragment from main activity and then via callback ask for current item

Comment: I did it even so thenks